# Cognos 10.1.1 unattended install - DB password required?

Tags: installation, cognos, cognos-10

I am trying use the unattended installation for Cognos Business Intelligence 10.1.1. I have the ats file configured and kick-off the installation. The problem is that I cannot seem find an option to provide the DB password in the ATS file. So during the installation, it prompts the user 
"Enter the password for [host]\cognos: "

This prevents me from creating an automation script.  I see in version 10.2 there seems to be a password section in the ATS file. I tried, but it does not work. Does anyone know how to configure system to avoid the interactive password prompt?

10.2 Sample ATS file (Dialog 9 is password section):
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEP7J_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.vvm_installation_guide.10.2.0.doc/c_vvm_sample_response_file.html

Comment: From a recent installation of 10.2.1 I could suggest not to use the installation applications but to create images of the applicable sub directories. Since IBM Cognos does not write registry entries the whole installation process boils down to copying the images and a call to Cognos Configuration to create the content space and create the encrytion keys. The former could be done away with by restoring a DB image.

Comment: The sample you've noted is for the Virtual View Manager product and not the base Business Intelligence package.  

Typically you wouldn't want a Derby database in situations where you're doing an unattended installation (the bundled DB is more for demo purposes).

Comment: @chsh: Yeah, I was just using that as an example of what I was hoping for. I not sure I understand about the Derby DB comment though. Do  you know of a way to configure system for password during installation?

Comment: Are you trying to do a silent install of a server?  Not sure I see much benefit to that, unless you have multiple servers to set up the same way. If that's the case, I would suggest installing one server manually, and then use the response.ats file from that install.

Comment: We are in test environment where the machines are wiped out often and re-installed. So we were trying for automated way to restore them to "testable" state.

Comment: Andrew's suggestion of doing a GUI install once and then saving the .ats file is your best bet if the documentation is lacking.  They should be equivalent in capability (unattended vs attended) and if they're not you should contact support.

Comment: First, thank you to Andrew. Your solution worked to get the configuration parameters I wanted. I also found another way to get around the password prompt. I used powershell to create the cognos user ahead time. Then ran the install as adminstrator which was able to switch to cognos user when needed at end.